# ListView:drawSelectorOnTop getting ignored in theme?

Tags: android, listview

In styles.xml, I've defined a theme, and a style for ListView items:

```
// styles.xml
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListView</item>
</style>

<style name="ListView">
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/my_red_selector</item>
</style>
```

I'm using ListFragment, and I can see the color for my listview selector is respected ("@drawable/my_red_selector"), but it seems like the drawSelectorOnTop attribute is ignored - my selector is still draw below.

If I define my own layout file and do:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    ...
    style="@style/ListView" />
```

then the drawSelectorOnTop attribute in the style is honored. Is there something I could be doing wrong here that's getting my selector on top attribute ignored?

Thanks

---- Edit ---------

Here is the definition of "my_red_selector":

```
// my_red_selector.xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_on"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_on"/>
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_on"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/transparent"/>
</selector>

// red_on.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

Comment: In the @drawable/my_red_selector are you trying to change the background color on focus?

Comment: Hi Sana, hmm maybe, I pasted my selector definition above, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution?  I'm having the same trouble.  A regular listview it works perfect, but a ListFragment fails to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below selector on your list item row of your ListView if you have a custom row

```
    <!-- Active tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_on" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Ok I gave that selector a try but same effect, gets drawn behind. My listview rows aren't doing anything funny either, they're just straight up LinearLayouts with no backgrounds specified or anything like that.

Comment: Is your ListView a custom listview or a standard ArrayAdapter?

Comment: It's a custom ListView in one case, in another case I'm using an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: So are we dealing with two listviews here?

Comment: Hi, yes I have a few listviews throughout my project, but they're in those two configurations (custom listviews, and arrayadapter listviews).

Comment: ok Lets start with the custom listviews first. So the row layout that you are using for your custom listview when you apply the background as the xml that I provided in the answer doesn't change the background to red?